# Malloc invalid conversion from 'void*'

Tags: c

I don't know much about malloc and I know there are similar questions but I still wanted to ask.

When I compiled my code I came across these errors

```
scheduler.c: In function 'char* addprocess(char*, FILE*)':
scheduler.c:127:60: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'process*'
scheduler.c:135:38: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'
scheduler.c:170:65: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'event*'
scheduler.c: In function 'int main()':
scheduler.c:381:52: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'stat*'
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
```

Here are the lines from the code.

```
127     struct process* newproc = malloc(sizeof(struct process));
135     newproc->name = malloc(line-pos-1);
170     struct event* newevent = malloc(sizeof(struct event));
381     statistics = malloc(amount* sizeof(struct stat));
```

What does it mean when it say invalid conversion and why. Also what is the best solution to these errors.

Comment: What command are you using to compile?  Are you using a c++ compiler, by chance?

Comment: I use this command line to compile 'g++  scheduler.c -o out'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code.

In C, a `void *` can freely be converted to or from any other non-function pointer without a cast.  In C++, a cast is required, which is why you're getting errors about converting to/from `void *`.

Use the C compiler to compile C code:

```
gcc scheduler.c -o out
```

Comment: Thanks, It did compile with no errors after chaining g++ to gcc. I have to watch out for these small things